# Shiny busy indicator without a bar

Tags: progress-bar, shiny, progress, shinydashboard

Is there any shiny busy indicator that not include the progress bar? just like the "please wait" animation when uploading shiny examples?

Comment: see user1603038's answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17325521/r-shiny-display-loading-message-while-function-is-running

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40395877/5894457) could be what you are looking for.