# Show a message instead of/within plot while data is loading in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

Is there a possibility in R Shiny to replace a plot with a "loading" message while additional data is loading? I am using a big dataset in my app and since not all data is always necessary, I split the data in two parts and initially load only a smaller sample.

Only when the full dataset is chosen in a dropdown menu, I load the full sample. Since loading takes some time and freezes the plot, I would like to show a message instead and show the plot only when the loading is done. Example:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("select_length","Length",choices = c("Short","Long"), multiple= FALSE, selected = "Short"),
  plotOutput("hist")
)

server <- function(input, output){
  rv <- reactiveValues()
  rv$df <- c(1,2)

  observeEvent(input$select_length,{
    Sys.sleep(5)
    df_new <- c(3,4)
    rv$df <- c(rv$df, df_new)
    },
    once = TRUE,
    ignoreInit = TRUE
  )

  output$hist <- renderPlot({
    barplot(rv$df)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I would like to show a plot with a simple "loading" message while the additional data is being loaded, e.g.:

```
plot(c(0, 1), c(0, 1), ann = F, bty = 'n', type = 'n', xaxt = 'n', yaxt = 'n')
text(x = 0.5, y = 0.5, paste("Data is loading..."), cex = 1.6, col = "black")
```

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/progress.html

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17325521/r-shiny-display-loading-message-while-function-is-running

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18237987/show-that-shiny-is-busy-or-loading-when-changing-tab-panels

Comment: Since shiny 1.1, you can show interactive contents while the additional data loads by using futures. See [here](https://www.rstudio.com/resources/videos/scaling-shiny-apps-with-async-programming/)

Answer (score 1):

You might like the ShinyBS package. I've used it for alerts when loading data before and it works great (it also looks fancy).

Here's an example of my usage....[image: Example]

This was the code used to create the alert, it's fairly simple. The user can exit it or you can call to delete as detailed below.

Server:

```
createAlert(session, 'upload_complete',title = 'Data Import Complete', content = 'You may continue to the other tabs', alertId = 'alert_delete', append = FALSE)
```

UI:

```
mainPanel(
....
bsAlert('upload_complete'),
)
```

Call to delete (in server)

```
closeAlert(session,'alert_delete')
```

Answer (score 0):

would it be acceptable to show a progress bar while the additional data is loading? Shiny RStudio show an example for displaying a plot - http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/progress-bar-example.html

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use library(shinycssloaders).

is very simple and professional.

1. `library(shinycssloaders)`
2. options like eg: `options(spinner.color="#0275D8", spinner.color.background="#ffffff", spinner.size=.5)`
3. add the loader with `withSpinner(Output method(objectname), type = 1-8)`

https://www.listendata.com/2019/07/add-loader-for-shiny-r.html