# R shiny busy global indicator

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

Is there a global busy indicator for R shiny/dashboard applications.
I do not want to set an indicator to each chunk everytime like the example given below:
https://mastering-shiny.org/action-feedback.html?q=progr#progress-bars

But I am looking for something that I want to set **once** and it will simple indicate busy notifications **whenever** shiny server is making a somewhat long calculations (10/30 seconds).

I think this should be a default behaviour of shiny but I could not see anywhere something like this.

I saw this library but did not work:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/shinybusy/vignettes/shinybusy-usage.html

Comment: A nice solution for the users is to use non blocking techniques like future/promise, [here is an example](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/promises/vignettes/shiny.html)

Comment: My current runs are only around 10/30 seconds. I think I should update the question.

Comment: I found this solutions looks doing what I want but not that elegant. Untill I find a better solution, I may use this one https://colinfay.me/watch-r-shiny/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show that Shiny is busy (or loading) when changing tab panels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18237987/show-that-shiny-is-busy-or-loading-when-changing-tab-panels)